# How can I get the text to appear on the left side of the checkbox?

Tags: html, css

suppose I have a checkbox, e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox">1</input>
```

It's going to appear like this:

[image]

Is it possible for me to get it to appear on the left of the text box, e.g.:

What do I need to do?

[image]

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no `</input>`

Comment: 2 downvotes? Is this an unreasonable question? Or was it because I hurt someone's feelings with the invalid HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<label>1 <input type="checkbox" /></label>
```

Comment: when you are wrapping input with label then there is no need of `for` attribute

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't put the number on the left side the way you are trying to do it, but one could do it this way:

```
<label>1</label><input type="checkbox"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is

```
<label>1<input type="checkbox"/></label>
```

Other way is

http://jsbin.com/uyohar/1